# Get Formatted Date in SQL Server CE

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-ce

How to get the formatted date in SQL Server CE?

I have a column on a table that contains `Date`, but the column type is `nvarchar`

```
ID     Date
----------------------
1      05/08/2012
2      10/08/2012
3      05/10/2012
```

The date format is `MM/dd/yyyy`, but it is in `nvarchar`.

Also, I want to have a `WHERE` clause to select the ID on a specific date. How can I do that? This is for SQL Server CE. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to cover it use convert or cast function ...

```
cast(datecolumn as DateTime)
```

or

```
 CONVERT(datetime,datecolumn,101)
```

Comment: Rama: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Yes, it works for the first code. And how to compare with the current date? I want to make it on a WHERE Clause, like: `WHERE cast(datecolumn as DateTime) = ...`?.  tried DAY(GetDate), NOW, CURDATE, GETDATE, still has no luck..

Answer (score 1):

For current date, you can use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar,GETDATE(),101)
```

> **Output:** (As of answered date)
>
> 05/31/2016